# Linkedin Api for python not working correctly

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

Linkedin Documents are confusing like crazy. I just want to get some basic information. I need to get a company's recent updates, comments for the update, and how many likes the update got. I tried to follow the documentation and this is my code:

```
from linkedin import linkedin
import oauth2 as oauth
import httplib2

api_key = '9puxXXXXXXX'
secret_key = 'brtXoXEkXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = '75e15760-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_secret = '10d8caXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
RETURN_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'

cos = oauth.Consumer(api_key,secret_key)

access_token = oauth.Token(key=auth_token, secret=auth_secret)

client = oauth.Client(cos,access_token)

resp,content = client.request("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1219692/updates?start=0&count=10", "GET", "")
```

This code is supposed to get the 10 recent updates for apple, but this is what I get when I

```
print resp
print content


{'status': '200', 'content-length': '78', 'content-location': u'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/216984/updates?count=10&oauth_body_hash=2jmj7l5rSw0yVb%2FvlWAYkK%2FYBwk%3D&oauth_nonce=87365476&oauth_timestamp=1372347259&oauth_consumer_key=9puxXXXXXXX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0&start=0&oauth_token=75e1576XXXXXXX&oauth_signature=EhcMiQXXXXXXX%3D', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': '*', 'server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'connection': 'close', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'date': 'Thu, 27 Jun 2013 15:34:18 GMT', 'x-li-request-id': '84BXIU5ZQK', 'x-li-format': 'xml', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not make sense, you imported linkedin module, which seems to be [this module](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin), but I can't see you are using that API wrapper in your code. If I'm wrong you can still use the wrapper above and easily handle data back from LinkedIn. Just take a look at this example:

[Querying updates](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin#company-api)

sample:

```
from linkedin import server

application = server.quick_api(KEY, SECRET)
application.get_company_updates(1035, params={'count': 2})
```

where 1035 is the ID of the company you are trying to get updates from.

Comment: When I just do the first line in your code: from linkedin import server, i get an error:  ImportError: No module named oauthlib.common

i googled it, but could not find any solutions

Comment: Yes well, if you read the linkedin python module documentation, you need a couple of modules:$ pip install python-linkedin
$ pip install requests
$ pip install requests_oauthlib